# Does this puzzle have a clear solution?

Tags: pattern

Just wondering whether anyone can see an unambiguous solution the reasoning test example below? Please explain your reasoning if possible. Thanks.

[image: Reasoning Test]

Comment: Some of the text in the image is unclear. Add a link?

Comment: At least you should identify the source of the question.

Comment: I wonder if others would consider this question well-formed.  To me it's ambiguous.

Comment: The movement of the puzzle is dictated by the right column of each set,
the right column from A becomes left column of B flipped with enlarged character.  The spacing of the arrow [top-right] of block E makes B in the answer selection set the winner.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is either A or B...

In each move:

- bottom right shaded symbol becomes top left hollow symbol
- top right symbol is rotated and enlarged to become bottom left symbol

I can't see any means of deciding between A and B - the horizontal alignment of the left column maybe? - so I'm going to go with *no*, I don't think there is a unique solution.

***Or*** if a feeble reason will do, then

- new symbol in top right must contain a vertical line

And then the answer is uniquely **A**.

Comment: I suspect it's B just because that way all the new symbols are different.

Comment: @Zandar It doesn't have to be new though, top-right in example 4 is the same as top right in example 2, just rotated.

Comment: Apparently this puzzle considers rotation enough to make a symbol different.

Comment: @Zandar, could be.

Answer (score 1):

It actually does make sense when you see the hint.

If a diagram is of the form

\begin{matrix}
    L & ᴎ  \\
    M & ⚫  \\
\end{matrix}

Then the next is of the form

\begin{matrix}
    \circ & P  \\
    \text{N} & Q  \\
\end{matrix}

Here $\circ$ was filled black in the first matrix and filled empty in the second and ᴎ was flipped vertically and enlarged. P and Q are new unused figures.

Hence the answer should be B. A doesn't work because the hollow arrow was used before. The diamond was used before too, but it was of different proportions. Look at the hint, it actually reveals the whole answer.

I could answer this quickly only because I saw the hint. I don't know how much time it would take me if I didn't (or if I could even solve it for that matter)

**Is the problem clear enough?**

It seems that A E has come up with a equally valid reasoning for A. In my opinion, the puzzle is unambiguous enough to discard options C,D,E. But differentiating between A and B is up to interpretation.

Comment: Why can't it be $A$?

Comment: @GentlePurpleRain Made an edit, The hint says the figures are new.

Comment: I think "new" is ambiguous; it could refer to the current iteration rather than the whole series.  There has already been an arrow, but there has also already been a diamond.  But this is likely the intended answer.

Comment: @dennisdeems Not in the same proportions.

Comment: @Anachor the symbol newness is block to/by block, not across the entire sequence/sets.

Comment: @moonbutt74 There is nothing in question to clarify that. There is nothing that suggests mine either, but it is a pattern puzzle which means you are supposed to figure these out by yourselves. Often this means these puzzles are open to interpretation which is the case here.

Comment: @Anachor , The pattern seems obvious enough, it IS a visual puzzle. If you are speaking to the whole question quality thing, this could become a conversation like the the one between Jack Sparrow and Davey Jones xD

Comment: @moonbutt74 How do you discard option A (as in AE's answer) or option B(as in mine).

Comment: @Anachor , hi, follow the spacing of the arrow and where it's pointing to, In A, the arrow is pointing to the corner of the shape above it, in B the arrow is pointing more inward into the shape and away from the corner. And again the spacing from the edge of the block itself. I will say if this turns out to be one of those stupid "none of the above" answers i'm going to scream.